# Lending website to someone else to get ads for the website

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies

My website has potential to generate nice revenue from advertising but as I live in Iran and google does pay to Iran, I'm not able to accept ads.

I have talked to a friend in Turkey to lend him my website so that he can apply for Google Adsense and I get 50% of the revenue generated by ads.

**Important:** Please take into consideration that I will move out of Iran after a year then I want to just activate my own account and get ads with my own account.

I wanted to know if this is legal or there might be a violation in google policies.

Comment: Why don't you read the adsense ToS?  That's what anyone who can answer would have had to do.

Comment: @Steve I have read it and I haven't found anything about lending.

Comment: Well, that should tell you something...